# Can Gitosis enforce correct user name/email?

Tags: git

Gitosis is able to authenticate users based on public/private key pair. It is able to find out which user is currently committing. However, the user name and email is taken from the client's Git configuration ('git config user.name' etc.), which can be set to arbitrary values. Is there any way to associate user names and emails with their public keys and then make Gitosis uses these names and emails as the name and email of the committer?

Edit: I do not care if I will use Gitosis or WebDAV or some other alternative to share the repository. It just seems to me that none of the available methods supports this enforcement of using some kind of "correct" user name and email. If there exists some alternative, please tell me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it yourself. A good starting point is to mix and shake the two examples "Enforcing a Specific Commit-Message Format" and "Enforcing a User-Based ACL System" of this [online book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-4.html)

Comment: Thanks for information. It is pretty long time since I asked this question and since then I started using Gitolite instead of Gitosis, and I was able to do something similar to what you suggest.